# LDAP at IBM XIV

Tags: ldap, authentication, ibm, utf-8, ascii

I have problem with authenticating users over LDAP (Active Directory)  Windows 2008 R2 on  IBM XIV.

After troubleshooting I've find out problems caused by polish letters in CommonName  (distinguishedName contain CN)

Users without polish letters in CN  works fine.

here output XCLI Session XIV with login without polish chars CN

XIV>> ldap_test user=test@domain.com password=p4ssword 
Command executed successfully

here output XCLI Session with polish chars in CN

XIV>>ldap_test user=test@domain.com password=p4ssword 
Error:   LOGIN_FAILURE_USER_NOT_AUTHENTICATED_BY_LDAP_SERVER
Details: User test@domain.com was not authenticated by LDAP server 'dc.domain.com'

I've google'd alot but ... found nothing special like documentation about ASCII characters only allowed:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/csec_chars.html

I have no idea what I can do now ... anyone have idea how to got it work with special polish letters ?
I do not want change CN to non polish letters in my AD :s

Comment: In your place I would IBM support :-)

Comment: @Law29 That's the first time I have seen IBM used as a verb.

Comment: @kasperd I think I an entire word

Comment: 1 week with mails t o IBM -  no answers  any1 have idea what to do now ?